# Getting help of R function using helpExtract function

Tags: r, helpextract

I can get help in `R 3.1.2` on `Yates` function from `FrF2` package through:

```
?FrF2::Yates
```

Now I want to get help in `.tex` format through `helpExtract` function unction which can be obtained from [here](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/3007ab692168f7150021) (written by @AnandaMahto). I tried this code but not working:

```
helpExtract(FrF2:Yates, section = "Examples", type = "s_text")
```

I wonder if there is any way to mention the package name in `helpExtract` function?

Comment: If you use [`helpExtract`](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/helpExtract.R) from ["SOfun"](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun), you should be able to specify the package.

Comment: Cool--@AnandaMahto. This works like a charm in `R 3.1.2` but fails in `RStudio Version 0.98.1091` and throws the following error: `argument 'object' must deparse to a single character string`. The arguments of `helpExtract` in `RStudio Version 0.98.1091` are `function (Function, section = "Usage", type = "m_code")`. However R show the following arguments `function (Function, section = "Usage", type = "m_code", ...)`. Any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will take a function name and return a package name:

```
 pkg <- function(fn) find( deparse(substitute(fn) )  )
 pkg(mean)
#[1] "package:base"
```

But I think it's going to have trouble with the ?pkg::func format so I pulled out everything before the last ":" with gsub:

```
pkg <- function(fn) find(gsub(".+[:]","", deparse(substitute(fn) ) ) )
pkg(base::mean)
[1] "package:base"
```